# Mapping a hardcoded value with ModelMapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

I'm evaluating the [ModelMapper library](http://modelmapper.org/) to map a project DTOs and Entities. Although the library is quite powerful, I could not find a way to map a hardcoded value from on Entity to its DTO representation.

The ModelMapper, maps a method from source class to a method on destination class. For example:

```
modelMapper.createTypeMap(MyEntity.class, MyDTO.class)
    .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.map(MyEntity::getName, MyDTO::setFirstName))
    .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.map(MyEntity::getSurname, MyDTO::setLastName))
```

But I've an attribute on DTO which is not present on the entity side yet. Using a Spring converter class, this mapping was always done by a hardcoded value like this `dto.setStatus("ACTIVE");`. But using ModelMapper I can't figure out how to do it properly. My first attempt was something like that:

```
    .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.map(s -> {return "ACTIVE";}, MyDTO::setStatus))
```

However, the mapping above does not work since ModelMapper expects to map a `get` method from the source. Thus, a return has no effect and in fact the code above results in runtime error.

A possible solution, which is quite ugly is to force the desired result with `using` helper like this:

```
addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(c -> "ACTIVE").map(MyEntity::getName, MyDTO::setStatus));
```

In this case, the `getName` method is used just to provide a `get` method while the real value will be replaced by `ACTIVE`. But since this is a unclear solution, I would like to understand whether there is a better solution to solve this **using ModelMapper**.

Another solution is add to my entity/dto a method `public String getStatus() { return "ACTIVE"; }`. But I really would like to keep all hardcoded values on mappers.

Comment: Here you don't map. You hardcode a value in the target object. Why using model mapper for this ? It seems more intricate as needed.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it is more intricate that it should be... But I've decided to ask since I did such mistake and 2 days later another dev asked me about the same thing... So the idea of keep static values on the mapper (instead of entity/dto) seems to be the preferred way for some devs.

Answer (score 1):

This is super old, but...

This worked for me:

```
this.mapper.typeMap(MyEntity.class, MyDTO.class)
        .addMapping(src -> "ACTIVE", MyDTO::setStatus);
```

*Note: addMapping VS addMappings*

Comment: Actually it also works with addMappings and the same exact syntax of yours